# plsql procedure talking forever to run

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This Procedure is compiling fine but taking forever to run. I think even for single row, it is taking too much time to process. Where should I change the code to make it run faster?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEWWAPTWOPROC(
  P_WAP NUMBER,
  P_DEALNO VARCHAR2,
  P_FDT DATE, 
  P_SECURITYCD VARCHAR2,
  P_SECURITYTYPE VARCHAR2,
  P_SELFORCONSTITUENT VARCHAR2
)
IS
  v_pofv NUMBER(30);
  v_sofv NUMBER(30);
CURSOR C1 IS 
SELECT
     D.SECURITYCD SCD,
   D.DEALNO DNO,
   S.OWNSTK OWNST,
   LAG(S.OWNSTK) OVER(ORDER BY D.DEALDT) PC_STK,
   D.Dealtype DTYPE,
     D.SECURITYTYPE STYPE,
     D.SELFORCONSTITUENT SFORCO,
     D.DEALDT DDATE , 
     D.PRICE PRC,
     D.FACEVALUE FV,
     LAG(D.FACEVALUE) OVER(ORDER BY D.DEALDT) PC_FV,
     D.WAP1 WP,
     LAG(D.WAP1) OVER(ORDER BY D.DEALDT) PC_WAP1
FROM MMDEAL0_NWAP D INNER JOIN Mmstock1 S
  ON D.Securitycd=S.Securitycd
  WHERE D.DEALDT>=P_FDT
  AND D.DEALNO=P_Dealno
  AND D.FACEVALUE>0
  AND D.Dealtype IN('PO','SO')
  AND D.Selforconstituent='S'
  AND D.SECURITYTYPE='DGS'
  ORDER BY 
     D.DEALDT,D.Securitycd;

BEGIN

FOR i in C1
LOOP
    if C1%rowcount=1 then
      UPDATE MMDEAL0_NWAP SET WAP1=P_WAP WHERE Dealno=P_DEALNO AND DEALDT=P_FDT AND
      SECURITYCD=P_SECURITYCD AND SECURITYTYPE=P_SECURITYTYPE AND
      Selforconstituent=P_SELFORCONSTITUENT;

    else
       IF i.OWNST>0 then
            if i.DTYPE='PO' then
              v_pofv:=i.FV;
            elsif i.DTYPE='SO' then
              v_sofv:=i.FV;
            end if;
        i.WP:=((nvl(i.PC_WAP1,0)*nvl(i.PC_STK,0))+(nvl(v_pofv,0)*nvl(i.PRC,0)))-(nvl(v_sofv,0)*nvl(i.PC_WAP1,0))/i.OWNST;

        UPDATE MMDEAL0_NWAP SET WAP1=i.WP WHERE DEALNO=i.DNO AND DEALDT=i.DDATE AND 
        SECURITYCD=i.SCD AND SECURITYTYPE=i.STYPE AND SELFORCONSTITUENT= i.SFORCO;
       END IF;
    end if;
END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
Dbms_Output.Put_Line(SQLCODE||' '||SQLERRM);
END NEWWAPTWOPROC;
```

Comment: @lucumt it's a [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html) so should be OK.

Comment: By the way, Oracle will print the error stack automatically if there is an exception, and `dbms_output` is for diagnostic and debugging messages and is often disabled in production, so all your exception does is hide exception details and make the procedure appear to succeed when it fails. Also `sqlcode` is the number that appears after the `ORA-` in `sqlerrm`, so concatenating it in an optional diagnostic message doesn't add any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `CURSOR` and loops for no reason when all your updates can be converted to an update and a `MERGE` statement.

This below is your update statement for the case `C1%rowcount=1`, which was not required to be put inside the loop even before.

```
UPDATE mmdeal0_nwap 
SET    wap1 = p_wap 
WHERE  dealno = p_dealno 
       AND dealdt = p_fdt 
       AND securitycd = p_securitycd 
       AND securitytype = p_securitytype 
       AND selforconstituent = p_selforconstituent;
```

The second update converted to `MERGE`

```
MERGE INTO mmdeal0_nwap t USING (
     SELECT i.*,
            ( ( nvl(i.pc_wap1,0) * nvl(i.pc_stk,0) ) + ( nvl(v_pofv,0) * nvl(i.prc,0) ) ) - ( nvl(v_sofv
           ,0) * nvl(i.pc_wap1,0) ) / i.ownst AS new_wp  --your calculation for the value of WP to be updated
     FROM (
          SELECT d.securitycd scd,
                 d.dealno dno,
                 s.ownstk ownst,
                 LAG(s.ownstk) OVER(
                      ORDER BY d.dealdt
                 ) pc_stk,
                 d.dealtype dtype,
                 d.securitytype stype,
                 d.selforconstituent sforco,
                 d.dealdt ddate,
                 d.price prc,
                 d.facevalue fv,
                 LAG(d.facevalue) OVER(
                      ORDER BY d.dealdt
                 ) pc_fv,
                 d.wap1 wp,
                 LAG(d.wap1) OVER(
                      ORDER BY d.dealdt
                 ) pc_wap1,
                 CASE
                      WHEN d.dealtype = 'PO' THEN d.facevalue
                 END
            AS v_pofv,
                 CASE
                      WHEN d.dealtype = 'SO' THEN d.facevalue      -- IF conditions converted to CASE
                 END
            AS v_sofv
          FROM mmdeal0_nwap d
          INNER JOIN mmstock1 s ON d.securitycd = s.securitycd
          WHERE d.dealdt >= p_fdt AND d.dealno = p_dealno AND d.facevalue > 0 AND d.dealtype IN (
               'PO',
               'SO'
          ) AND d.selforconstituent = 'S' AND d.securitytype = 'DGS'
     ) i
     WHERE i.ownst > 0                              --outer IF condition
)
ON (
     t.dealno = s.dno AND t.dealdt = s.ddate AND t.securitycd = s.scd AND t.securitytype = s.stype AND
     t.selforconstituent = s.sforco
)   --where clause from your update
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.wap1 = s.new_wp;
```

Please note that the code is **untested**, so you may have to fix some syntactic errors / editing mistakes which I may have made. But, I believe I have given you fair enough idea how to proceed.

Comment: Untested for sure (we don't have those tables), but yes: +1 for a non-loop suggestion.

Comment: Well, if you're wrong, I'm wrong too. Maybe someone else will join too. You know how it goes - if you keep telling a lie long enough and frequent enough, it becomes true, eventually :) So, update / merge it is (or will be).

Comment: @Littlefoot : Yes and apparently our only hope is to wait for the OP's  confirmation and it looks like there is no sign of it yet.

Comment: **Kaushik Nayak* Thanks For the code, of course, you have given, I don't know the best idea to proceed. _Merge_ seems to the smart idea for these kinds of scenarios thanks @Littlefoot you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some general suggestions for investigating PL/SQL performance:

1. Add `dbms_output` messages containing counts and timings (or write the details to a log table). This may be tricky if the code never completes or produces too much output, but you may be able to create some simplified test data to limit the run.
2. Step through the code in the debugger until you can identify the issue, for example if some value is not being reset as expected or a loop is not being exited. It will also give you a feel for how long each step takes. (Desktop tools have different ways to launch the debugger, but they should all provide the feature.)
3. Use [`dbms_profiler`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_profiler) to get a report on how many times each statement is called and much time is spent on it. Again you may need to restrict the run with simplified test data. Profiling is built into some desktop tools such as PL/SQL Developer so you can just click a button, or else it's straightforward to use on the command line. (There is also [`dbms_hprof`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/plsql-hierarchical-profiler-11gr1), although it's more complicated to use for little benefit, and [`dbms_trace`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_trace), although in my experience this doesn't tell you anything useful.)
4. You can tell a lot about what it is doing by querying `v$session` from another session. Some desktop tools have session monitors built in to make this easier.
5. If you have licenced the Diagnostics and Tuning Pack, you can get a lot of useful run-time information out of [`v$active_session_history`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/active-session-history).
6. You can monitor running or recently completed SQL with [SQL Monitor](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/real-time-database-operation-monitoring-12cr1). If you have access to it, Oracle Enterprise Manager / Cloud Control gives you a lot of this via a convenient browser based dashboard. I would also take each SQL statement and test it on the command line to make sure it did what I expected and completed in a reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I will look up and follow These debugging and performance tester techniques. These are very helpful Thank you so much again. :)